# changing x-axis labels to date ranges

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this data

```
                    DT Msc zdarzenie Sub Objetosc.norm
1  2022-01-12 18:00:00   1         1  11          22.9
2  2022-01-12 19:00:00   1         1  12          32.2
3  2022-01-12 20:00:00   1         1  13          24.9
4  2022-01-23 18:00:00   1         2  21          19.4
5  2022-01-23 19:00:00   1         2  22          33.8
6  2022-01-23 20:00:00   1         2  23          25.7
7  2022-01-24 19:00:00   1         3  31          20.9
8  2022-01-24 20:00:00   1         3  32          34.1
9  2022-01-24 21:00:00   1         3  33          25.8
10 2022-03-10 18:00:00   3         4  41          20.2
11 2022-03-10 19:00:00   3         4  42          32.1
12 2022-03-10 20:00:00   3         4  43          21.8
13 2022-04-03 19:00:00   4         5  51          19.0
14 2022-04-03 20:00:00   4         5  52          39.9
15 2022-04-03 21:00:00   4         5  53          26.3
```

A prepared plot in ggplot has numerical markings as x-axis labels

```
ggplot(Kotl.gaz.sel.pyt) +
  geom_col  (aes(x = Sub/10, y = Objetosc.norm, fill = factor (zdarzenie) )) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5),
        legend.position = "none",
        legend.justification = "center") +
  facet_wrap(~Msc)
```

I would like to display a time and date stamp. Example below. This is not necessarily the final solution, but only shows what information I would like to include in the figure

[image]

Comment: In your example, it would seem `Msc` correlates with the month. You could extract the date and facet wrap according to it and map timestamp to `x`. *edit* Now that I think about it, "Msc" might mean "Mesec" in your language, which would translate to... month. Sorry for just being verbose. :)

Comment: Msc means month (in my language - miesiąc, PL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could do it by setting breaks and labels in `scale_x_discrete`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
dt_plot <-
dt %>% 
  mutate(DT = as.POSIXct(DT, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"),
         date = format(DT, "%y.%m.%d")
         ) %>% 
  group_by(date) %>%
  filter(DT == min(DT)) %>% 
  mutate(dt_label = format(DT, "%H:%M\n%y.%m.%d")) 
      

  ggplot(dt) +
  geom_col  (aes(x = as.factor(Sub), y = Objetosc.norm, fill = factor (zdarzenie) )) + 
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = dt_plot$Sub,labels = dt_plot$dt_label) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1),
        legend.position = "none",
        legend.justification = "center") +
  facet_wrap(~Msc, scales = "free_x")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>